# Launch Screen Image size for all iOS screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to create a lunch screen image for my iOS app. But I am not sure whats the right size for it.

According to apple website for iPhone 6 the size should be 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait.

But my question is, **how to create a launch screen image that will fit for all screen sizes such as iPhone 5, 5s, 6, 6 plus, iPads etc?**

Whats the correct way of doing this?

Comment: have u tried make one big image and resize it using constraints?

Comment: Don't create launch screen images. Use a launch screen storyboard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to images.xcassets
there you can see launch image sizes.Just Enable iOS version from right side.
iPhone Portrait iOS 8:- 1242*2208 (5.5 inch)
                        750*1334 (4.7 HD)

iPhone Landscape iOS 8:-2208*1242 (5.5inch)

iphone Portrait iOS 7,8 :- 640*960 (@2x)
                           640*1136 (Retina)

iPhone Portrait 5,6 :- 320*480 (@x)
                       640*960 (@2x)
                       640*1136 (retina4)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I create different version of the launch image each with a corresponding size to the iPhone screen sizes and add them in the image.xcassests? Do I need to do anything in the code? will the iPhone select the correct image from the image.xcassests based on which iPhone the user has?

Comment: Yes you have to create different versons of launch images & add them to assets.No need of any code.iPhone will select correct image.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @poojathorat, Could you please help me to check out my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955856/different-launch-screen-image-or-background-image-sizes-for-ios-devices    ?

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is, how to create a launch screen image that will fit
>   for all screen sizes such as iPhone 5, 5s, 6, 6 plus, iPads etc?

That will be very hard to do. The devices have different aspect ratios and the difference in size between say iPhone 5 and iPad Air is pretty big to use one image for all. If you want to use the classical launch screen with a screenshot, resizing one image won't look the same as the user interface on different devices. If you want a launch bitmap **image** you will need to supply all the necessary sizes.

> Whats the correct way of doing this?

You can create either launch PNG image or launch screen as a storyboard.

For launch image, your project has an assets catalog. Either use existing or add new **iOS launch image**. The editor will show you all required sizes.

For a storyboard, your application probably already has LaunchScreen.storyboard. You typically won't create specific size or sizes here, but use auto layout that will resize the screen appropriately.