# Image sizes for launchscreen storyboard with an image asset

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am moving my launch screen from the launch asset to the new approach of launchscreen.storyboard. However I am confused as to what size images do i need to provide for the 1x 2x and 3x image assets. The images are full-screen images with a little bit of text. Ideally I want the images to be generic so that they are visible properly on all sorts of iphone devices from iph5 to iph11.

I have tried a few images but they seem to get stretch or behave differently on regular iphones and iphone x variants(the images seem vertically stretched). I tried looking on apple forums for a solution but couldnt find anything concrete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch Screen Image size for all iOS screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114162/launch-screen-image-size-for-all-ios-screen-sizes)

Comment: you need to set constraints accordingly

Comment: see apple guideline for launchscreen images ... and set constraints ... set imageview content mode accordingly

Comment: @NayanDave No, that approach is now old and i am using a storyboard with image asset not the launch screen asset thing.

Comment: @jawadAli I have done that all the constraints are set and content mode is set but the image that i have to provide in the image set as 1x 2x and 3x i am confused what size should those be and how to get them to look same on all devices

Comment: @Rishabh, the whole point of using a storyboard for launch screen is not to use an image fully. Instead, create a view, add your labels, give background. Let the background be in content mode fill. Align your text labels just like you do in view controllers. Add multiple image views to handle other images. Set your constraints. The same launch screen storyboard can be even used for the iPad app.

Answer (score 1):

For each scale factor (@1x, @2x, @3x) you'd want to have an image that is large enough for the largest device you support.

For example, the resolution of a 12.9" iPad Pro is 2048x2732 with a scale factor of 2x. Therefore, if you want to have a universal background image for all @2x devices supporting both display orientation (portait and landscape), you'd need a 2732x2732 image (i.e. 1366x1366@2x). The same is for the @3x iPhones where you want a 2688x2688 (i.e. 896x896@3x) image because the resolution of the large Plus iPhones is 1242x2688. If you support old non-retina devices, you'd probably go with 1024x1024@1x, that was enough for non-retina iPads.

On the launch storyboard, you need to set the constraints and the content mode of your image view depending on your background image.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) provide a list of different image sizes for various devices.

However, if your launch screen doesn't have a complex background but rather a solid color fill, consider getting rid of the background image completely.